# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' error

Tags: python

```
def display(self):
    temp=self.start
    print "list is\n"       
    while temp.next==None:
        print temp.data
        print "\t"
        temp=temp.next
    print temp.data
    print "\n"
```

Comment: what is "self", you have to provide more code?

Comment: To answer this we'd have to know what `self.start` is. Apparently it's nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be handling a linked list. You should be only be looping over the nodes if the next node is **not** `None`:

```
while temp.next is not None:
```

Because you are looping while `temp.next==None` is true you end up setting `temp` to `None` with `temp=temp.next`. Note that this would only ever happen if your linked list consisted of just one element.

You almost certainly want to test `temp` itself here, and use `print ...,` to omit the newline `print` would otherwise write:

```
while temp is not None:
    print temp.data, '\t',
    temp = temp.next
```

That way you can set `self.start` to `None` to signal an empty linked list, and you'll not skip the last element in the linked list (which will have `node.data` to print but have `node.next` set to `None`).

You should really use `is` and `is not` to test for `None`; there is only ever one `None` object in a Python program (Python never creates copies of it, it is a singleton). Although `== None` and `!= None` will work, it is better to use `is None` and `is not None`.

Comment: Maybe it's worth stating the `==` is equality while `is` is identity and that there is only a single `None` object, also, maybe it should be `while temp is not None`